# generate and ID based in one condition

Tags: r

I have  100 pdf medical reports of different persons, I included each report into a list in R, they have two columns with a lot of different information each one, but I just want the reports that have the gallbladder tissue, so I want to create an ID for the all report nut only the rows that contain the word "gallbladder". Then I want to filter only the gallbladder reports to extract further information.
These is how it looks each element of the list (They have much more information)

```
list[[1]]                           
report  text    text_2      
1       name    andres      
1       tissue  gallbladder 
1       rut     11455698

list[[2]]                           
report  text    text_2      
2       name    ana     
2       tissue  liver       
2       rut     5556678
```

I want to create the ID according to tissue : `gallbladder`

```
list[[1]]   
report  text    text_2          ID
1       name    andres          1
1       tissue  gallbladder     1
1        rut    11455698        1

list[[2]]           
report   text   text_2         ID
2        name   ana            0
2        tissue liver          0
2        rut    5556678        0
```

### then i want to filter only the reports that the `ID==1`

I tried many ways but i just have the ID for the row, not for the all report.

```
list[[1]]   
report  text    text_2          ID
1       name    andres          0
1       tissue  gallbladder     1 
1       rut     11455698        0

list[[2]]           
report  text    text_2         ID
2       name    ana            0
2       tissue  liver          0
2       rut     5556678        0
```

Maybe you have some ideas!
Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We may loop over the `list` with `lapply`, then create the `ID`, column by checking if there are `any` value in 'text_2' column as "gallbladder" - `any` ensure to return a single `TRUE/FALSE` which gets recycled for the entire data in the `list` and this logical column is coerced to binary with `as.integer` or just `+`

```
list2 <- lapply(list, function(x) 
     transform(x, ID = +(any(text_2 == "gallbladder"))))
```

Comment: thank you for your help, but it didnt create any ID variable, just transform each list in a formula. The original lists for each reports have one colum whit the all report information, it is called text variable , and i splited generating text_2 that conteins gallbladder, maybe there is an space, because i believe that is not working becasuse it is not identify these part text_2 == "gallbladder"

Comment: I used `list2` instead of `list`

Comment: @CONSTANZAFABIOLAGonzalez If you have splitted the single column, then it is the input data you showed in the post